# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException while navigating back - Win8

Tags: c#, windows-8, navigation, comexception

As soon as my app starts sync will happen where in data is fetched from the server. I show a progress bar (indeterminate) to indicate the same. Suppose I navigate to another page while the sync is happening and then press back I get the COMException.

Any idea as to why this happens? What is preventing the app from navigating back to the first page.
Im using `this.Frame.GoBack();` to go back.